# How to get specific elements from cookie in header

Tags: express, jwt, authorization, backend

So I'm using JWT for authorization and trying to use private routes, but I'm having a slight problem. When I check my request header, I can see my token appearing in the Cookie header, but it looks like this.
[Here is my cookie from my request headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGCgY.png)

Is there anyway to get just the token part from my cookie? I only know how to use `req.headers["cookie]` to get the whole cookie, but then I also get the stuff I dont want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm, all I had to do was split it and access the 2nd element in the created array like this `req.headers["cookie"].split(" ")[2]`